# How do I ask the user for a filename to use as the input file?

Tags: c, file, file-io, input

this is my first post, so I hope I'm doing everything correctly.
I've already searched google and this site, but I couldn't find the answer I was looking for.

I am trying to prompt the user for a file name and inputting this filename into fopen.
When I try running and inputting an existing text file (with .txt extension), I still run into my filenotfound error message.

Here's my code so far (just trying to get the file open right now):

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){
int c;
FILE *file;
char filename[99];
fgets(filename, 99, stdin);

file = fopen(filename, "r");

if (file) {
    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
        putchar(c);
    fclose(file);
} else{
puts("FILE NOT FOUND");
}
return 0;
}
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with me putting it into an array of chars? Is there some way to make a string out of them or is it something else?

Comment: "I'm guessing it has something to do with me putting it into an array of chars?" -- C is not my forte, but I'm pretty sure an array of chars _is_ a string in C.

Comment: @Brian S Just a note: In C, "A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character."  Without the `\0`, an array of chars is not a string.

Comment: A pedantic solution would scan the string, maybe skipping leading whitespace, looking for legal filename characters and then verifying the the remainder of the string is whitespace.  But then how does one accept strange filenames that only consist of spaces?  Who knows - or cares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fgets`() retains the newline ( \n ). You need to remove it. One way to do that is to change:

```
fgets(filename, 99, stdin);
```

to

```
fgets(filename, 99, stdin);
char *p = strchr(filename, '\n'); // p will point to the newline in filename
if(p) *p = 0; // if p is not null, terminate filename at p
```

Comment: Okay, you cross-posted while I deleted my comment (I was talking about \r being possibly read by fgets).

Comment: @Étienne  I noticed windows to be troublesome with `stdin` from time to time as it appears to open on binary mode presenting a `\r\n` on "Entry key".  To fix I've tried `freopen(NULL, "rt", stdin);` to force it into text mode and collapse the `\r\n` into `\n`.  Can't speak to the quality of this fix though.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to figure it out, but your code seems more robust/efficient. Thanks!